# How to sum times from Time datatype columns in hh:mm:ss?

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sum

I have a SQL Server table with 4 columns (`TIME(0)` datatype).

Each row correspond to a day so I have:

```
Col Time 1 -------- Col Time 2 ------ Col Time 3

'03:23:12' -------- '21:33:04' ------ '07:44:11'
'21:14:45' -------- '12:43:44' ------ '01:56:43'
'15:22:36' -------- '19:33:55' ------ '04:03:11'
'08:21:46' -------- '01:23:14' ------ '06:09:11'
```

I want to `SUM` each column so I can get the *total hours, minutes and seconds* (`hh:mm:ss`).

So for example for `Col Time 1` I should have:

```
48:54:46
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider refactoring the database, I'm not convinced this is very good design...

Comment: You are not storing a `time` you are apparently storing a duration. You should use an `interval` data type for that. If SQL Server supports that (not sure about that). If it doesn't you should probably store durations as a single value that represents the duration in seconds, rather than a `time` which is *not* a duration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*At first*, your final value should be `48:22:19` instead of `48:54:46`.
*Secondly*, you can't use `TIME` type to receive the result you want, because *element range for `hh` is two digits, ranging from `0` to **`23`**, that represent the hour( [More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb677243.aspx) )*.

Here comes a workaround, when at first you `SUM` `TIME` column converting each value in *seconds* and then find separately *hours, minutes and seconds* :

```
SELECT CAST(t.time_sum/3600 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':'
     + CAST(t.time_sum%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':'
     + CAST(((t.time_sum%3600)%60) AS VARCHAR(2))
FROM ( SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00:00', col1)) AS time_sum
       FROM tbl) t
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7ea7/45)

Answer (score -2):

I found much easier way to do this..

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(column_name)))
```

Comment: You found this in MySql I assume. The question is tagged for SQL Server.