# SQL Server - Sum time display issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found the following formula on stack overflow which has helped me sum up time values, which works brilliant after tweaking it slightly:

```
SELECT CAST(t.TotalHours/3600 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':'
     + CAST(t.TotalHours%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':00'
FROM ( SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00', WorkingHours)) AS TotalHours
       FROM workhour) t
```

from [SQL How to sum times from Time datatype columns in hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160572/sql-how-to-sum-times-from-time-datatype-columns-in-hhmmss)

**However** I am now having an issue in terms of formatting. When I run this query on my data, it returns the time sum in this format: `HH:M:SS (32:0:00)`

My Data:

```
WorkingHours
   05:30
   06:00
   05:30
   08:00
   07:00
```

Expected Output:

```
  TotalHours
   32:00:00
```

As you will notice, my data does not consist of seconds, so I have added that at the end as a string. Its the minutes that appear to be causing me an issue.

**Question:**
Is there a way to tweak the above forumla so that I can get the total to display as `HH:MM:SS -> 32:00:00`

**NOTE**: *This occurs when the minutes field returns 0, or has a value of less than 10...*

Thankyou for the help in advance. I am using SQL Server 2016 Data Center, and have the data stored in my table as a varchar in the format HH:MM, called WorkingHours.

**Working Answer:**

```
SELECT CAST(t.TotalHours/3600 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':' +
     RIGHT('000' + CAST (t.TotalHours%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':00'
FROM ( SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00', TotalHours)) AS TotalHours
       FROM workhour) t
```

Comment: Can you show your original data and expected output

Comment: Be methodical.  Get the hours, minutes and seconds individually, then concantenate them.

Comment: my data is the original data from my table, and the expected output has been added below

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for the suggestion, ill give that a go

Comment: Sum time values? That makes no sense... What's half past seven plus a quarter to eleven?

Comment: basically a timesheet application is what this is coming from, I have 5 days in a week, and I want to sum the total time during that week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
RIGHT('000' + CAST (t.time_sum%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

This will take the 2 right-most characters of the concatenation of '000' and the calculated minutes. So if your minutes are less then 10, a `0` is added in front. Resulting in `01` - `60`.
I always use more `0` than I'm going to need, just because it doesn't matter, and I'll always be safe.

Comment: @Crezzer7 just remember to do it on hours as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Right('0'+cast(yourvalue as varchar(2)),2)
```